# Получение доступа к центру BorderPane в JavaFX

Tags: javafx

Необходимо получить доступ к центральной области BorderPane, чтобы организовать скрытие всего, что находится в центре. Есть код:

```
public class MainApp extends Application {

private Stage primaryStage;
private BorderPane rootLayout;

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
    this.primaryStage.setTitle("Курсы повышения квалификации");

    initRootLayout();
}

/**
 * Инициализирует корневой макет.
 */
public void initRootLayout() {
    try {
        // Загружаем корневой макет из fxml файла.
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("view/RootLayout.fxml"));
        rootLayout = (BorderPane) loader.load();

        // Отображаем сцену, содержащую корневой макет.
        Scene scene = new Scene(rootLayout);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

    } catch (IllegalStateException | IOException e) {
    }
}



public void hideOverview() {
    primaryStage.getScene().getWindow().getScene().getRoot().setVisible(false);
}
```

Метод hideOverview() должен скрывать то, что находится в области CENTER BorderPane`a, но моя реализация скрывает объекты всех областей. Как быть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Node root = primaryStage.getScene().getWindow().getScene().getRoot();
if ( root instanceof BorderPane ) {
    ((BorderPane)root).getCenter().setVisible(false);
}
```